# Goa'uld starships

Tags: stargate

It's stated that the rings are ancient tech and there are a few other things that are known to be ancient technology or derivitive, but it seems that they tend to leave the technology in the form they found it in. We also know that the Goa'uld stole their ship tech, however the designs and efficiency look nothing like the Asgard, Ancient, or Nox designs we've seen.

Is there any info as to where the ship tech came from?

My best guess is that it came from the Furlings. This makes sense to me, because the Furlings, acording to the "supposed to be canon games" say that the Furling created the Goa'uld and the few tech pieces we've seen from them seem to be fairly primitive and unimpressive compared to the other advanced races. Are ther any canon sources that support this or say where their ship tech comes from? And if it comes from the Furlings, why it is so weak comparitively to the other 4 in this alliance?

Comment: There's no indication whatsoever to suggest (or even imply) that the Goa'uld's technology came from the Furlings.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on whether you acknowledge [*Stargate Worlds*](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_Worlds) to be cannon.
Originally, *Worlds* was to be released between S08 and S09 most likely in the style of [*Defiance*](http://www.defiance.com/en/). It was to be fully cannon. The release was cancelled and some information about the game and the story has been released.

Some confirmed data from the game:

> The overarching story for the game at launch was centered around the return of Ra and his attempt at reconquering the galaxy with the aid of remaining Goa'uld and Jaffa die-hards and his new army of Straegis - an alien species invented for the game.
>
> The Straegis were going to be revealed as the Furling species, damaged and enslaved by Ra.
>
> Players were to discover that each of the races had constructed a potential "caretaker" species to carry on existence in the Milky Way after it had gone.
>
> The Furling were to have said to create the Goa'uld as their caretaker species.

It is not a far reach to infer that the Goa'uld defeated and enslaved the Furlings through the use of Furling technology. If the Goa'uld could not fully comprehend this technology, it is reasonable that they simply salvaged what they could and were therefore not as advanced as the remaining three races of the Alliance.

Unfortunately, the only other [confirmed cannon](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_canon) sources are *SG-1*, *Atlantis*, *Universe*, the role-playing books, and the Fandemonium novels; none of which have anything more than a passing reference to the Furling.

Comment: Good answer, especially in regard to the (non) canon status of the cancelled game.